# Why the span value didn't bind with input in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, antd

when I changed input value,span value didn't match with my expected change.
here is my jsx file:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './Avatar.less';
import { Input } from 'antd';

var typed = '';

function changed(e){
    console.log(typed);
    typed = e.target.value;
}

const Avatar = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.normal}>
     <span>{typed}</span>
     <Input onChange={changed.bind(this)} placeholder="text in" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Avatar;
```

Comment: Did some of the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use React's `state` functionality so it will re-render when the value of `type` changes. Basically your app could look like this:

```js
const {Input} = antd;

class Avatar extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {style: ''};
 }
 onChange(e) {
  this.setState({typed: e.target.value});
 }
 render() {
  return ( 
   <div className="normal">
    <span>{this.state.typed}</span>
    <Input onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} placeholder="text in" />
   </div>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <Avatar/>,
 document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
.normal > * {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/antd/dist/antd.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you change a `typed` variable, which does not trigger component re-rendering.

You need to read the react [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) about a component life-cycle. For triggering component update you usually need to change the state or pass new properties.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rtkhanas/93gue7be/1/) is a working example for you.

Comment: what is different between `const Avatar = () => {}` and `class Avatar extends React.Component {}` ?  I init project with scaffold command and this is the default code style.

Comment: Your style is a functional style, you define component as a function. It is a long story about that as well, but I would say it is good to use it. However in this case we need a local state in our component to be able to trigger component update, in this case it is easier to define component as a class. Nothing bad in that, it is really common approach.

Comment: You can use functional style if you store the state somewhere outside, like using Redux or Flux architecture, but in this step it is better just learn React well. Only after that I would recommend learning Redux or Flux.

Comment: very appreciate for your advice,this functional style can't set state